# React Native error - "animated node with tag does not exist?"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, expo

I'm having a pretty nebulous error occurring when I change `useNativeDriver` from false to true in my React Native expo app. From something like this:

```
if (headerMenu._value > moderateScale(120)) {
      Animated.spring(headerMenu, {
        toValue: moderateScale(80), 
        bounciness: 0.5,
        useNativeDriver: false, //change to true
        speed: 0.2
      }).start(toggleHeaderMenu(false));
```

Where headerMenu is the height of a view:

```
  <Animated.View
      style={
        (styles.topBar,
        [
          {
            height: headerMenu,
            overflow: "hidden",
            paddingVertical: 5,
          },
        ])
      }
    >
```

I get error

> Animated node with tag does not exist

[image]

Most answers are not helpful / don't give a clear reason why this is happening. This doesn't occur with other Animations. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

React native Animated does not support native driver on height animation
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated#caveats
i would recommend using react-native-reanimated for animations
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated

Comment: Ok. I need to get the animations on the same thread as they would be if useNativeDriver: true - will this package accomplish that/

Comment: yes. It is a bit complicated to get started, you will need to refactor your animations by quite a lot. But there's already some good tutorials on Reanimated 2 out there like this one for example https://youtu.be/dowHt1dckDU to get you up and running. In my personal opinion Reanimated is a must have if you plan on developing a serious application in react-native. Reanimated api is much much better than rn-Animated api.

Answer (score 2):

Using `expo upgrade` fixed the issue for me.

Initially, I only manually upgraded my expo version to the latest version which was `41.0.1`. However, that still gave me the same error. After I used `expo upgrade` it upgraded multiple packages and that worked for me. Just for reference, the packages that got upgraded were:

> @react-native-async-storage/async-storage, @react-native-community/async-storage, @react-native-community/masked-view, expo-ads-admob, expo-app-auth, expo-camera, expo-google-sign-in, expo-image-picker, expo-linear-gradient, expo-local-authentication, firebase, react-native-appearance, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-screens, react-native-svg, react-native-webview, react-native, react, react-dom, @babel/core, expo